# Training Program to become stronger alpine Skier?

Tags: programs, muscle-endurance, lower-body-strength, skiing

I'd like to hear from someone who is more of an advanced downhill skier, like someone who has competed in slalom or mogul events, or is a veteran back-country skier.

**Is there a template program you followed to become a stronger skier, something suggested to you by a coach or a personal trainer?**

**Is there a specific muscle group in your core or lower body you would suggest focusing on?**

It can be either for moguls, slalom, glades, back country, whatever I like all kinds of skiing. I'm already a good skier, I just want to become better, and I think being physically stronger in the right places can help just as much as going out on the mountain and putting a bunch of hours in.

This is not a duplicate of [this question](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/3052/what-is-a-good-exercise-to-prepare-for-skiing/3060#3060) which is the closest I could find, because this post just talks about someone with knee problems.

Comment: If you are not already generally strong, the best answer is probably to avoid sport-specific strength training and work on general strength training first.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a ski instructor who is working on similar things. I picked up a copy of "Total Skiing" by Chris Fellows, and it has a lot of useful information.

Specifically, it has a set of evaluations for physical strength and balance, and then a set of exercises to work on for each of the areas.

Comment: Can you delve further into what those evaluations and exercises are? Having that extra information here and referencing the book would make this a better answer.

Comment: Agreed, a quick run-down of the exercises he suggests would be great!

Comment: I think it's unfair to the author to list the exercises he recommends, and I don't think it would work that well; the point of the evaluations is that they are used to decide which exercises are important.